Tensor product of a Verma module of the highest weight and a Verma module of the lowest weight, $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$
$\DeclareMathOperator\sl{\mathfrak{sl}}\newcommand\hw{\mathrm{hw}}\newcommand\lw{\mathrm{lw}}$Consider $\mathfrak{g}=\sl_2(\mathbb{C})$. Fix $\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{C}\setminus \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, and we may assume that $\lambda+\mu\in\mathbb{C}\setminus \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$.
For the vector space $M^{\hw}(\lambda)$ with formal basis $\{v_{\lambda-j}: j\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} \}$ we define action of linear operators $E$, $F$ and $H$ as
$$
H(v_{\lambda-j})=2(\lambda-j)v_{\lambda-j},
$$
$$
E(v_{\lambda-j})=j v_{\lambda-j+1},
$$$$
F(v_{\lambda-j})=(2\lambda-j)v_{\lambda-j-1}.
$$
For the vector space $M^{\lw}(\mu)$ with formal basis $\{w_{\mu+j}: j\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} \}$ we define action of linear operators $E$, $F$ and $H$ as
$$
H(w_{\mu+j})=-2(\mu-j)w_{\mu+j},
$$
$$
E(w_{\mu+j})=(2\mu-j) w_{\mu+j+1},
$$$$
F(w_{\mu+j})=j w_{\mu+j-1}.
$$
Here $M^{\hw}(\lambda)$ is a Verma module of the highest weight $\lambda$, and $M^{\lw}(\mu)$ is a Verma module of the lowest weight $\mu$.
For $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in\mathbb{C}\setminus \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ such that $\lambda_1+\lambda_2\in\mathbb{C}\setminus \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ it is easy to obtain that
$$
M^{\hw}(\lambda_1)\otimes M^{\hw}(\lambda_2)=\bigoplus\limits_{J=0}^\infty M^{\hw}(\lambda_1+\lambda_2-J),
$$
and similarly for the tensor product decomposition of two Verma modules of the lowest weight.
The question is to find how to decompose $M^{\hw}(\lambda)\otimes M^{\lw}(\mu)$. The complication which emerges is that one apparently runs into direct integration, since Casimir operator seems to have a continuous spectrum.
EDIT: The resulting module has to have a countable basis, yes. But if I take the Casimir operator $C$ and act with it and comultiplication $\Delta$ on a weight vector of a form $u=\sum\limits_{i,j=0}^\infty a_{i,j} v_{\lambda-i}\otimes w_{\mu+j}$,
$$
\Delta C (u)= A u
$$
gives a system of equations on coefficients $\{a_{i,j}\}$ and the eigenvalue A. Even though this system can be separated into subsystems, where we fix $i-j=\alpha$, $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}$, unfortunately, there appears to be no conditions restricting the eigenvalue $A$(as opposed to a system of equations in the case of $M^{\hw}(\lambda_1)\otimes M^{\hw}(\lambda_2)$). Hence, I assume, one should integrate over it somehow. I apologize in advance if I am mistaken.
Any hints on how to proceed, any references in this direction will be appreciated!

Sorry for my naive comment : how can the Casimir have continuous spectrum since a basis of that tensor product is countable?

@NicolasHemelsoet Dear Nicolas Hemelsoet, thank you very much for your question! I have also asked this question myself when approaching the problem, hence, decided to add the answer to it to my original post.

Actually, this tensor product won't contain any lowest weight vector. So it can't contains any $M^{lw}(\nu)$. Similarly, it won't contain any $M^{hw}(\nu)$, so you won't be able to express this tensor product in term of Verma modules.

@NicolasHemelsoet True! My naive guess is that it should be something known as dense modules. See, for example, Volodymyr Mazorchuk "Lectures on $\frak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$-modules", Section 3.3. But even if it is true, I don't know how to rigorously obtain this result.

Yes, theorem 3.32 and the comment above imply that this tensor product has a filtration by modules $V(\xi_i, \tau_i)$'s, but I don't know if it splits and how to calculate the $(\xi_i,\tau_i)$.

The theory of direct integrals works well in the context of unitary representations on Hilbert spaces. May I suggest rephrasing the question in the context of unitary representations on Hilbert spaces of the Lie group $\widetilde{SL(2,R)}$ (the universal cover of $SL(2,R)$), after imposing the additional constraint that  and  are negative real numbers (to ensure unitarity)? Note that the tensor product of Hilbert spaces is not the algebraic tensor product – it is a completion of the algebraic tensor product. I am very interested in the answer to that question.

@AndréHenriques Dear Professor Henriques, thank you very much for your wonderful suggestion! I have seen something along those lines considered in the works of Ip, Ponsot, Teschner. However, I can't change representation space and I can't impose the additional constraint you have mentioned. The problem I have described in the post has certain origins, which are not allowing me to do so.
